# Prevent list of uploaded files in blueimp jquery file uploader at the time of pageload

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, amazon-s3, blueimp

At the time of pageload when blueimp fileupload is initialized it fetches all the uploaded files. I have to disable this feature so that uploader don't access the uploaded file list.

It is taking almost 30-40 seconds to initialize because my uploaded list is around 3k. Which is not necessary to show while uploading file.

So i want to prevent blueimp library to send always empty list of files which were uploaded to s3.

Please help if any one has any idea regarding it. I am using jquery blueimp uploader to upload files directly to s3.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use the provided example with the included `main.js`? If so, delete/uncomment the lines from `Load existing files:` to the end of the following `$.axax()` call.